# MySQL - return records for clients unless they have a specific value and only that value

Tags: mysql

Trying to wrap my head around how to do this query - I want to return a list of client records and need to exclude clients if they had only a specific value and no other values.

For example

```
c#    value
1     X
1     Y
2     X
3     Y
```

I want all the records for clients 1 and 3, since they had a value other than X.  I do not want client 2, because that client had ONLY X.

I for example want returned in this case:

```
1  X
1  Y
3  Y
```

Of course, I could have lots of other records with other client id's and values, but I want to eliminate only the ones that have a single "X" value and no other values.

Maybe using a sub-query?

Comment: Show your desired results

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT client, value FROM myTable where `client` in 
  (select distinct(client) from myTable where value !='X');
```

Returns:

```
Client   Value
1        X
1        Y
3        Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT ABB2.* 
FROM 
mytable AS ABB2
    JOIN
        (SELECT c 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE value <> "X"
        GROUP BY c) AS ABB1 ON ABB1.c = ABB2.c
GROUP BY ABB2.c, ABB2.value
```

It's faster than using a WHERE clause to identify the sub query results (as in Mike's answer)